# Javascript Bar chart with number volumes from database not displaying in php webpage

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts

I am trying to display the number of bookings per month on a bar chart , i have two seperate sql queries which i have tested and both read back the data in the correct format. However when i run the file in browser nothing display nor do i get errors in my console. Below is my code.

```html
<?php
$host = "localhost";
 $user = "root";
 $pass = "";
 $db = "paperlesspub";
 
 $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
        

$month = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT MONTH(booking_date) FROM `booking`");
$sales = mysqli_query($conn, "select Month(booking_date) as Month, count(customer_ID) as Booking FROM booking GROUP BY month(`booking_date`)");


?>
```

This is my chart code

```html
<script>
            var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: <?php while ($b = mysqli_fetch_array($month)) { echo '"' . $b['MONTH(booking_date)'] . '",';}?>],
                    datasets: [{
                            label: '# of Bookings',
                            data: <?php while ($p = mysqli_fetch_array($sales)) { echo '"' . $p['count(customer_ID'] . '",';}?>],
                            backgroundColor: [
                                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                            ],
                            borderColor: [
                                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                            ],
                            borderWidth: 1
                        }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: true
                                }
                            }]
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does the generated JS look like?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're missing the opening bracket (`[`) for your arrays.

here...

```
labels: <?php while ($b = mysqli_fetch_array($month)) { echo '"' . $b['MONTH(booking_date)'] . '",';}?>],
```

and here...

```
data: <?php while ($p = mysqli_fetch_array($sales)) { echo '"' . $p['count(customer_ID'] . '",';}?>],
```

should be...

```
labels: [<?php while ($b = mysqli_fetch_array($month)) { echo '"' . $b['MONTH(booking_date)'] . '",';}?>],
```

and...

```
data: [<?php while ($p = mysqli_fetch_array($sales)) { echo '"' . $p['count(customer_ID'] . '",';}?>],
```

Comment: i still cannot get my chart to load

Comment: i have checked the network and i am getting a 200 ok for my result

Comment: please share any errors in the browser console (press F12 on most)